# Disconnect from ssh2_connect()

Tags: php, ssh, disconnect

I've connected over ssh2 using `ssh2_connect` to a server, but I don't see any method [in the manpages](http://php.net/ssh2_connect) for how I should end the connection.

I'm not exactly a fan of waiting for a script to end before I disconnect.

Can I use `fclose`? That doesn't sound right...

Comment: I don't know the answer, but from what I got reading the docs `fclose()` should be used in combination with `ssh2_exec()` and `ssh2_shell()` calls, but I don't think it applies to `ssh2_connect()`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just [`unset($connection)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) your connection variable or `ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');` might do it.

You could probably do the following in order to be even more convincing!

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
unset($connection);
```

Comment: +1, The `unset()` could be done only if `ssh2_exec()` is not a resource (or returns `false`).

Comment: Alternatively: `ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit') or unset($connection);` should do it.

Comment: `ssh2_exec( $conn, 'exit' )` and `ssh2_exec( $conn, 'logout' )` do _not_ kill the session. All they do is exit from the temporary shell used to execute the command. The SSH session still exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), you could do `$ssh->disconnect()`.  phpseclib's destructor calls it but you could call it manually as well.

Answer (score -4):

`ssh2_exec('logout')` should kill your session…

Comment: In the event where command execution is allowed. I'm looking to kill the TCPIP, not use the protocol, because I can end up with `Warning:  ssh2_exec() [function.ssh2-exec]: Unable to request command execution on remote host`

Comment: `system('kill -9 ' . getmypid())`, hideous as it is, works in this instance.